# Unable to connect to my router admin page

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

Initially I browsed to http: //192.168.1.1/, entered the username and password and went to the "access control" subsection of the "management" section of my router. (An UTStarcom WA3002g4 modem of DataOne BSNL).

In this access control section I entered the ip address of vk.com thinking that the site will be blocked. But when I clicked on save and checked the 'disable' radio button, suddenly the webpage refreshed and showed the message 'The webpage is not available' and 'The connection to 192.168.1.1 was interrupted.' Since then I'm unable to access the router admin page. I'm able to use the Internet, it is just the routers webpage which is blocked.

Please help me...

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't typed anything wrong?. How about doing a router reset?

Comment: All routers have a reset button and a method of pressing it to restore factory settings, either a long press, or holding it down while powering on. Check with the manual.

Comment: You've probably added the address to only allow connections from on the management page of your router. It's probably going to be easiest to reset your router to factory defaults. You'll have to reconfigure any custom changes you made but this should be trivial as opposed to spending (wasting) hours trying to fix the problem.

Comment: is there no other way than resetting the router because i don't know if any custom settings were in place.

Answer (score 1):

As other wrote, you intended to block access to vk.com, but instead you configured your modems control panel to only allow access from that IP.

Since you are not using the vk.com IP, you can not access the modems webpage.

There are only two solutions:

- Access the modems configuration page using the IP address which you just entered. (Which would require cooperation from someone upstream since you are unlikely to be in that range yourself. Read: Either help from someone at vk.com, or help from your ISP which would need to isolate you from the net and pretend to be vk.com in order to access your modem.  Not to mention your router must already be configured to allow access to the configuration pages from the WAN side. This is unlikely).
- The second option is to reset the modem to factory defaults.

I recommend the latter, using [the reset pinhole is at the bottom of the router](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0n3QBMbljU), near the front-right leg.

Comment: is there any way to know my current settings of the router by using command prompt or something like that so that i can do the same settings after resetting the router..

Comment: If the router allows this and you made backups: Yes.  If the router allows other methods of access (e.g. ssh) then also yes. If you did not save them or if said methods are disabled or not supported, then no.